# Passing string between UIViewControllers.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

In ViewContrller1.h :

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *myString;
```

In ViewController2.m , I want to read a value from a text box and assign it to viewContrller1.theString and go to ViewContrller1

I used this method but I get a null value of my string in ViewContrller1:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    ViewContrller1 *go=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewContrller1"];
    go.myString=self.myTextFeild.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:go animated:YES];

}
```

Wondering how it suppose to work?

Comment: Your code seems correct. The possible problem I see is with self.myTextFeild.text. Maybe the IBOutlet to that textfield is not set correctly

Comment: set a breakpoint on the second line of the method, and inspect the value of myTextField and myTextField.text. What do you see?

Comment: @duricanRadu it is set in viewcontrller1.h as a (retain,nonatomic) should it be strong instead??
thank you

Comment: @RobP How is that done, thank you

Comment: I'm talking about self.myTextFeild not go.myString. Make sure that the  outlet from your xib/storyboard is connected to myTextField

Comment: You definitely need to learn how to use the debugger a bit, saves TONS of time and makes these problems easy to fix. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

To pass properties between 2 views, the recieving view must have a public property. For example, your VC 2 shoud have a public NSString. This means declared on your .h file. Then on your initial VC you have to pass the string on the `prepareForSegue` method. Something like that here:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vc2segue"]) {

        UIViewController *vc=segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.publicNstring=self.someTextView.text;

    }
```

}

Comment: isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, the same thing as what?. Storyboards and Segues are the standard way to move from one scene to the next and also to pass data back and forth. Calling viewControllers by code is not usual any more.

Answer (score 0):

try to simple import viewcontrller1.h in the new view controller.

```
#import "viewcontrller1.h"
```

Marcal's answer should also work.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you've posted, assuming you've made no typos and have connected the text field and the button to your second view controller (the one sending the string) and that you've added the Storyboard ID to the first view controller within your storyboard - see here http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html

Assuming you've also embedded the view controller within a Navigation Controller, then a line of code in viewcontrller1.m (viewDidLoad:):

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.myString);
```

Should confirm it works. In fact, I just tested it with your code and it works. Check for typos would be my advice if you've done all of the above.

Comment: Yeah i did all that and wrote the nsLog and it print Null 
THank you

Comment: Have you assigned the two view controllers the correct custom classes? Filled out the StoryBoard ID name for viewcontrollr1? Spelt "myTextFlied" the same in property as the method? Have the navigation controller as your initial view controller and viewcontroller2 wired up to it? Imported the viewcontrollr1 class into the second view controller as suggested by UserAwesome?